# SQL ordering stacking

Tags: php, html

I have this:
http://screencloud.net/img/screenshots/e796a906e816a8c44f9be15ed37d1735.png

As you can tell, on the right, it shows the same order as it does on the left. I don't want it to basically show that. I want it to where, as I post news articles, it'll stack but show the oldest on the left. If you understand what I mean.

I don't want this: http://screencloud.net/img/screenshots/d9be1bd327b31c523094e19510ff4922.png

where if a view looks to the right, they see the same article. The code I have for the left for the full article is this:

```
$grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "' LIMIT 1");    
$grab = mysql_query("SELECT id, news_title, news_content, news_author, news_day, news_month, news_year, news_date FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC limit 4");
```

What I have on the right is this:

```
$grab = mysql_query("SELECT id, news_title, news_content, news_author, news_day, news_month, news_year, news_date FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC limit 8");
```

would you guys happen to know what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I also added an "ASC" but it stays on the oldest articles in the database, and it doesn't move.

Comment: @TrippedStackers how do you want it? what is to be left, what is to be right?

Comment: @michi basically when I post a new article the 4th article "adssad42352" would go to the top of the "Recent" articles box on the left..

Comment: Not sure what you are wanting, but if you want the results in reverse order you can take the array from php and do [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for MySQL's OFFSET keyword:

```
SELECT id, news_title, news_content, news_author, news_day, news_month, news_year, news_date FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC limit 8 offset 4
```

Or, even simpler:

```
SELECT id, news_title, news_content, news_author, news_day, news_month, news_year, news_date FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC limit 4,8
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this LIVE DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a05db/8

use `LIMIT X,Y` with X = starting # of row and Y = number of rows...